# Using two different font sizes in math mode

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

Please see the below code:

```
\begin{small}
\[\begin{array}{l}
Some math that should be displayed in small font

\begin{tiny}
some math that should be displayed in tiny font
\end{tiny}

some more math in small font

\begin{tiny}
some more math that should be displayed in tiny font
\end{tiny}

\end{array}\] 
\end{small}
```

My code only shows the math code in small. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: `\begin{small}`  and `\begin{tiny}`  are wrong to begin with, they are switches, not environments. `{\small }`

Comment: Blank lines in math mode are an error.

Comment: @Johannes_B that comment is not really correct

Comment: Could you please show a real world example, possibly with motivation?